# POST method receive duplicated in server

Tags: ios, post, request

I'm sending a POST request to server but they receive it duplicated with the same date and even time. this is my code :

```
-(void) getTerms{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        User *mUser = [[User alloc]init];
        NSString *appFile1 = [self getUserFile];
        mUser = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:appFile1];
        NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Method=GetFAQ&CustomerID=%@",mUser.customerID];
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[post length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[ServerName serverName]]];


        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        NSURLConnection *theConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            if( theConnection ){

                // other codes

            }

        });

    });

}
```

I just wonder what is wrong with my code ? thanks in advance

Comment: how is the method being executed? from a call or button??

Comment: which ios version are you using ? I am having the same problem

Comment: Im using 8.1 @LenaBru but I solved it . let me post my code as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i solved the problem :

```
-(void) getCredit{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Method=%@",mMethod];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [ServerName postToServer:post];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{                
            NSURLResponse *requestResponse;
            NSData *requestHandler = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&requestResponse error:nil];

            NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[requestHandler bytes] length:[requestHandler length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil];
            NSDictionary *res1 = [res objectForKey:@"ServerResponse"];
        });  
    });
}
```